# Order of the conditions inside a python while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Why dose the order of the conditions inside a while loop create different results. For example

```
nums = []
k=3
while (nums[-1]<k and nums ):
    print('*')
```

gives error `list index out of range`

But this one doesn't show any error

```
nums = []
k=3
while( nums and nums[-1]<k ):
    print('*')
```

Comment: See [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: `and` will short circuit so `nums` evaluates to falsey since its empty, so `nums[-1]` never gets evaluated in the second version, but would otherwise be out of bounds.

Comment: If the part before the `and` is falsy, the second part is not even evaluated.

Comment: "and" evaluates its operands one at a time; in this case, for your first example, the "and" evaluates "nums[-1]<k" and, indeed, "nums" has no last element.   Because the first comparison is false, the second is never executed.

Comment: Note, also, that the short-circuiting behavior is intentional and provided to deal with precisely the sort of code you've presented.  It only. makes sense to access `nums[-1]` if we know that `nums` isn't empty.  Rather that needing to write `if nums:` and then on the next line `   if nums[-1]< k:`, Python lets you be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is expected behaviour, if an empty list is accessed by any index (-1 or any), it always throw exception reason being to access an empty list.

`num[-1]` represents the last element in the list. And `num=[]` is an empty list. Hence num[-1] will always throw exception in this case.

```
while nums and nums[-1]<k :
```

is safe condition as it first checks whether list contains elements or not, if it contains then only nums[-1] get executed.

Comment: Clearly the error is related to the order of the conditions - as you say in your “answer”: `as it first checks… then…` first says there’s an order/sequence to the tests. Very confusing.

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Why not mention short-circuiting with a link to the docs and also a link to where the docs describe truthy/falsey would be useful for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back and look at this without using any loops. Assuming we have an empty list like below:

```
nums = []
```

What would you expect `nums[0]` to do? How about the below:

```
nums[-1]
```

In both cases above, an *index error* would be raised, because the list `nums` is empty (it contains no elements, so there are elements within `nums` to access).

Now let's make it a little more difficult. How about the following:

```
last_num = nums and nums[-1] or None
```

Actually, that should be same (roughly) as the below:

```
last_num = nums[-1] if nums else None
```

This above syntax is a common idiom that implements a "safety check", meaning it retrieves the last element if `num` is a non-empty list, or a default value of `None` otherwise.

Comment: Why not mention short-circuiting with a link to the docs and also a link to where the docs describe truthy/falsey would be useful for a beginner.

Comment: @balmy I'm not sure - I wasn't following the discussion above. would you be able to add that in? thanks